# Cleanse Hibernate from my object but don't lazy load

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization, lazy-loading

I have an JPA+Hibernate entity that I need to send via RMI to a client that doesn't know Hibernate, so I've made a method to "cleanse" Hibernate from it:

```
// shortened
public class Player {
   private Set<Item> ownedItems;
   public void makeSerializable() {
      ownedItems = new HashSet<Item>(ownedItems);
   }
}
```

However, when I call `makeSerializable` Hibernate will attempt to lazy-load `ownedItems` if it's not loaded yet, which I don't want, and which is also impossible because there is Hibernate session. Instead, if `ownedItems` is not loaded, I'd like to set it to null or an empty set.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (!Hibernate.isInitialized(ownedItems)) {
    ownedItems = new HashSet<Item>();
}
```

This is the way to test if a collection is initialized without the need for a session.